# Send information to an iOS app from a Raspberry Pi Zero W via Bluetooth

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send data to my iPhone from my Raspberry Pi. I set up bluetooth on the Pi and I am able to connect to it on the iPhone. In a bluetooth inspector app that I downloaded, I am clearly able to see the UUID of the service that the Pi is advertising, but it says "Service was advertised but not yet discovered"

Here is my code

```
from pybleno import *
import array
import sys
from builtins import str
from builtins import range
import threading
import time
import random

class EchoCharacteristic(Characteristic):

  def __init__(self):
    Characteristic.__init__(
      self, {
        'uuid': 'a64e8b82-4b3c-444a-b379-0a066c910740',
        'properties': ['read', 'write', 'notify'],
        'value': None
      })

    self._value = array.array('B', [0] * 0)
    self._updateValueCallback = None

  def onReadRequest(self, offset, callback):
    print('EchoCharacteristic - onReadRequest: value = ' + str(self._value))
    callback(Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS, self._value[offset:])

  def onWriteRequest(self, data, offset, withoutResponse, callback):
    self._value = data
    print('EchoCharacteristic - onWriteRequest: value = ' + str(self._value))

    if self._updateValueCallback:
      print('EchoCharacteristic - onWriteRequest:     notifying')
      self._updateValueCallback(self._value)
    callback(Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS)

  def onSubscribe(self, maxValueSize, updateValueCallback):
    print('EchoCharacteristic - onSubscribe')
    self._updateValueCallback = updateValueCallback

  def onUnsubscribe(self):
    print('EchoCharacteristic - onUnsubscribe')
    self._updateValueCallback = None
  def update(self, newValue):
    self._value = array.array('B', newValue)
    if self._updateValueCallback:
      self._updateValueCallback(self._value)

def getData():
  return [random.randint(0, 100)]

def main():
  bleno = Bleno()
  echoCharacteristic = EchoCharacteristic()
  def updateCharacteristic():     # background thread function
    while True:
      newValue = getData()
      echoCharacteristic.update(newValue)
      time.sleep(1)
  thread = threading.Thread(target=updateCharacteristic)
  thread.start()
  
  def onStateChange(state):
    print('on -> stateChange: ' + state)
    if state == 'poweredOn':
      bleno.startAdvertising('Echo', ['a64e8b82-4b3c-444a-b379-0a066c910741'])
    elif state == 'poweredOff':
      bleno.stopAdvertising()

  bleno.on('stateChange', onStateChange)

  def onAdvertisingStart(error):
    print('on -> advertisingStart: ' +
          ('error ' + str(error) if error else 'success'))
    if not error:
      bleno.setServices([
        BlenoPrimaryService({
          'uuid': 'a64e8b82-4b3c-444a-b379-0a066c910741',
          'characteristics': [echoCharacteristic]
        })
      ])

  bleno.on('advertisingStart', onAdvertisingStart)

  def onDisconnect(clientAddress):
    bleno.stopAdvertising()

  bleno.on('disconnect', onDisconnect)

  bleno.start()

  print('Hit <ENTER> to disconnect')
  input()
  bleno.stopAdvertising()
  bleno.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

It should just be sending a random number that updates once per second. The UUIDs are random. Any advise is appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn’t the solution that anyone wants, but I solved this problem by starting over with NodeJS instead of python, and it worked. I pretty much made an exact port of the code and that fixed it. I had to use node 8.9.0 and install python 2.7 (for one of the dependencies) so Bleno is definitely a bit out dated, but it solved the issue. If you’re still trying to run it with python, perhaps try installing python 2?